# Why is limit Register needed in Page based memory management?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

Using the limit register,we can know the length of the segment from base.

But in page based Memory management ,Each page size is fixed and also not contiguous in RAM(as frames),So what is need of limit register here??

Comment: Assuming intel, is this 32-bit mode or 64-bit mode?

Answer (score 0):

In the newer CPU's it's not used anymore.

In modern systems the segmenting is just set to flat mode (the base is 0x0, the limit is the end of memory) so basically the whole memory is in one segment.

It's mostly for legacy purposes, just like Real Mode.

Answer (score 0):

The Intel chips have always been bizarre. The architecture looks like it was designed by modern artists on crack.

In 32-bit mode you cannot have pages without segments. That's an odd system but that's how Intel made it. The segments are the primary means of implementing memory protection. Therefore, it must have property defined segments. It makes no sense to have segments and pages but intel did it that way.

In 64-bit mote there are no segments (kinda sorta).